# need a solution for this "Error in chk.H2OFrame(x) : must be an H2OFrame"

Tags: r, data-science

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose())
View(data)

col_names <- c("Scrip Name", "Date", "Open", "High", 
               "Low", "Close", "Tick", "Volume")

colnames(data) <- col_names
View(head(data))

data$Date <- NULL
data$Tick <- NULL

#shifting n rows up of a given variable
shift <- function(x, n) {
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

data$shifted <- shift(data$Close, 1)
tail(data)

#remove NA observations
data <- na.omit(data)
write.csv(data, "data.csv")

#Installing the package
install.packages("h2o")

#loading the library 
library(h2o)

#Initializing the Virtual Machine using all the threads (-1) and 16gb of memory
h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "16g")
describe(data)

h2o.importFile("data.csv")
h2o.importFile(file.choose())
h2o.describe(data) # getting the error here as "Error in chk.H2OFrame(x) : must be an H2OFrame
"
```

i am running this code with some stockmarket's excel data of around 500 stocks and want to run the code to make some prediction but at the last step of "h20.describe(data)" i am getting the above mension error and i need a solution for it.

Comment: i am attaching the file for reference

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DK0xPEgcA7MncCr8X4aVoiSIFFmKgxOg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You use `data` which is only a data frame from the previous code (`read.csv()` at the beginning). You probably need to either convert the existing data frame to `H2OFrame` with [`as.h2o()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/as.h2o.html):

```
data <- as.h2o(data)
```

or read the CSV file with [`h2o.importFile()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.importFile.html):

```
data <- h2o.importFile("data.csv")
```

just before running `h2o.describe(data)`.